# select multiple div inside for-loop for group add/delete functionality in angular4

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a scenario in angular 4 environment,where i need to add/delete multiple members simultaneously,so inside a ngFor loop i have multiple divs but i want to select those div on which i click and for sure i'll click on multiple div at any given time.I could solve this only for one div meaning i could select only one div at any tine.

Please find the code snippets:

```
<div class="gp-row tomato-grower flexbox" *ngFor="let item of data.nonmembArray;let i=index">
                <div class="pack flexbox" [ngClass]="{'active': clickedItem === i }" (click)=selectNonMember(i)>
                    <img src="url" alt="Tomato Grower" class="circle-with-border" height="64" width="64">
                    <div class="text">
                      <div class="name">{{item.profile.first_name +' '+ item.profile.last_name | slice:0:13}}</div>
                      <div class="city">Hyd</div>
                      <div class="phone">+91 7897897891</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Function implementation:

```
  selectNonMember(i:number)
  {
    this.clickedItem =i; 
    // console.log(i);
  }
```

And css::

```
 .active
  {
    border: 3px solid grey;
  }
```

Please resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this problem by having the ngFor and the event binding in the same element, that way you can pass and show the class depending on where the user clicked

```
<div class="gp-row tomato-grower flexbox" >
  <div class="pack flexbox"
       *ngFor="let item of data.nonmembArray;let i=index" 
       [ngClass]="{'active': clickedItem === i }" 
       (click)="clickedItem = i">
    <img src="url" alt="Tomato Grower" class="circle-with-border" height="64" width="64">
    <div class="text">
      <div class="name">{{item.profile.first_name +' '+ item.profile.last_name | slice:0:13}}</div>
      <div class="city">Hyd</div>
      <div class="phone">+91 7897897891</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Also you were missing some "" around the function called in (click)

Comment: Thanks Nicolas for the direction but even after making that changes,i could select only one div at any given time,i think something is missing there and i am at loss of idea...

Comment: Because i want a functionality like selecting multiple elements simultaneously in a group.Please help